# Cast<T>() with a Type variable

Tags: c#, linq, casting, enums

I am trying to make a method to enumerate any *enum*, by returning a list containing each constant name and value.

Here's my code:

```
Type enumType = typeof(SomeEnum);
var enumConstants = 
    Enum.GetValues(enumType).
         Cast<enumType>().
         Select(x => new { Value = (int) x, Name = x.ToString() });
```

<sub>(I declare `enumType` in this snippet but it is in fact declared in my method signature as `MyMethod(Type enumType)`. I am not showing my method signature because that would require to introduce some *struct* I am using, which is not relevant to the problem here)</sub>

The problem is that this code does not compile and I am getting on the `Cast<enumType>().` line the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'enumType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't understand how can `enumType` be unknown, I just declared it on the previous line!

Note that on the `Enum.GetValues(enumType).` line, there is no error flagged.

Am I missing something here? Is some LINQ playing tricks?

Comment: Generic type parameters must be `T`, not `typeof(T)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics don't allow you to pass an instance of a variable, you'll need to either use `Cast<SomeEnum>()`, or make the method where this code lies generic, and use something like `Cast<T>()`.

Answer (score 5):

This should be:

```
Type enumType = typeof(SomeEnum);
var enumConstants = 
    Enum.GetValues(enumType).
     Cast<SomeEnum>().
     Select(x => new { Value = (int) x, Name = x.ToString() });
```

The problem is the `Cast<T>()` call.  The generic method type needs the actual type specification (`SomeEnum`), not a `System.Type` (`enumType`).

Comment: I can't do `Cast<SomeEnum>` by design, because I don't know `SomeEnum` in my method. My method will be called like `GetEnumValues(typeof(SomeEnum))`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    Type enumType = typeof(SqlDbType);
    var enumConstants =
        Enum.GetValues(enumType).
             Cast<Enum>().
             Select(x => new { Value = Convert.ToInt32(x), Name = x.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
Cast<enumType>()
```

to

```
Cast<SomeEnum>()
```

Comment: Can't do that. The purpose of my method is to *not* know what is the *enum*. My method will be called like `GetEnumValues(typeof(SomeEnum))`. Should have made that clearer in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

here is what I have

```
namespace SO.Enums
{
    public enum SomeEnum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type enumType = typeof(SomeEnum);
            var enumConstants =
                Enum.GetValues(enumType).
                     Cast<SomeEnum>().
                     Select(x => new { Value = (int)x, Name = x.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));
MyEnum[] values = (MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
int[] intValues = values.Cast<int>().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", names[i], intValues[i]);
}
```

---

Or in a more concise way:

```
var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
    .Cast<MyEnum>()
    .Select(x => new { Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), x), Value = (int)x });
```