# .Net Framework 4.8: Cannot cast Enum.GetValues result to System.Enum

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I need Something like

```
var enumConstants =
        Enum.GetValues(enumType)
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .Select(x => ...);
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525141/10807094). But I get `InvalidCastException`.

**Update:**

Sorry, the problem was somewhere else. I had something like:

```
var enumConstants =
        Enum.GetValues(enumType)
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .Select(e => new SomeClass{Value = (int)Convert.ChangeType(e, e.GetTypeCode()), ...}).ToList();
```

and apparently `Value = (int)Convert.ChangeType(e, e.GetTypeCode()` caused the problem. Which I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure the InvalidCastException is not in the code you omitted? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @YongShun: No, System.Enum is definitely *not* a namespace.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, I'm sure; ```.Cast<Enum>()``` produces the exception.

Comment: Why does it work for me, then?

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks for testing it. You are right, and I was wrong. I'll try not to be so sure in the future. I wrote an update about what I think was the cause of the error.

Comment: Does simply `Convert.ToInt32(e)` work?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an enum as below:

```
    public enum yourEnum
    {
        A1,
        A2,
        A3,
        A4
    }
```

You can use the following code:

```
var enumValues =Enum.GetValues(typeof(yourEnum)).
         Cast<yourEnum>().Select(x => new { Value = (int)x, Name = x.ToString() });
```

Probably the problem with your code is `.Cast<Enum>()` which should be `.Cast<yourEnum>()`.

Comment: +1. Although in my case casting to ```Enum``` is more favorable, because I have ```MyEnum``` as a generic type parameter, and unfortunately a type constraint of ```Enum``` is not possible. Anyways, this solution with some undesired changes made it work for me. Thanks.